# Pictures not displaying when i upload website

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi im working on a website for a college project and when i upload it via filezilla to the colleges hosting thing only 1 of the images displays and the text is all messed up 
here is it running in chrome just the html file
[image]

here is the webpage when i access it through the colleges hosting thing still using chrome
[image]

what could be the problem here?

Comment: The paths to the images are wrong when running on the server. Sadly we can't help you as you haven't shown any code.

Comment: the image paths just use  images/Human.jpg for example

Comment: try "./images/Human.jpg" or, if youre writing from an inner folder, such as /css/style.css you must do it with 2 dots like "../images/Human.jpg". My advice is to avoid the use of capital letters in file names and paths.

Comment: sorry guys when you said check the file paths i realised some of the paths had been set with lowercase i in images which has fixed the problem

Comment: @pvtctrlalt add you code to question

Answer (score 0):

check for image path and if the server are linux check for upper and lower case as well because linux server are case sensitive ..and also check for image file extension if it is .png or .jpeg and also if its in upper case or lower case if not please share the code